# Connection Issues After Updating to Studio 3T 2018.6.1

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, studio3t

Previously, It was working on Studio 3T 4.3 but now not able to connect my mongoDB server.

Authentication Method used - Legacy (SCRAM-SHA-1)

Showing me an error ->

[Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQS0h.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post that might help: https://studio3t.com/whats-new/connection-issues-with-2018-6/

tl;dr, it's likely happening if you're:

- using MongoDB 2.6 or lower, or
- using 3.0 or later binaries without having upgraded MongoDB-CR credentials